# Using nltk.FeatureExtractor for feature extraction

Tags: nlp, nltk, feature-extraction

I have been trying to use "nltk.FeatureExtractor" to extract relations on a block text.Here is the code I used

```
rtepairs = nltk.corpus.rte.pairs(['rte3_dev.xml'])[33]
extractor = nltk.RTEFeatureExtractor(rtepairs)
pprint.pprint(extractor.text_words)
```

But simply returns an empty set.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
from nltk.corpus import rte

nltk.download('rte')
```

use this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).